# Why does Maxmind's GeoLite2 City database return non-existent geoname_id?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

I've downloaded the latest updates of the Maxmind's GeoLite2 City database (both in MaxMind DB binary and CSV formats). When I tried to look up "88.184.98.0" here's what I got:

```
{"city":{"geoname_id":2982652,"names":{"de":"Rouen","en":"Rouen","es":"Ruan","fr":"Rouen","ja":"ルーアン","pt-BR":"Ruão","ru":"Руан","zh-CN":"鲁昂"}},"continent":{"code":"EU","geoname_id":6255148,"names":{"de":"Europa","en":"Europe","es":"Europa","fr":"Europe","ja":"ヨーロッパ","pt-BR":"Europa","ru":"Европа","zh-CN":"欧洲"}},"country":{"geoname_id":3017382,"is_in_european_union":true,"iso_code":"FR","names":{"de":"Frankreich","en":"France","es":"Francia","fr":"France","ja":"フランス共和国","pt-BR":"França","ru":"Франция","zh-CN":"法国"}},"location":{"accuracy_radius":5,"latitude":49.4431,"longitude":1.0993,"time_zone":"Europe/Paris"},"postal":{"code":"76100"},"registered_country":{"geoname_id":3017382,"is_in_european_union":true,"iso_code":"FR","names":{"de":"Frankreich","en":"France","es":"Francia","fr":"France","ja":"フランス共和国","pt-BR":"França","ru":"Франция","zh-CN":"法国"}},"subdivisions":[{"geoname_id":11071621,"iso_code":"NOR","names":{"de":"Normandie","en":"Normandy","es":"Normandía","fr":"Normandie"}},{"geoname_id":2975248,"iso_code":"76","names":{"de":"Seine-Maritime","en":"Seine-Maritime","es":"Sena Marítimo","fr":"Seine-Maritime","pt-BR":"Sena Marítimo"}}]}
```

However, there's no corresponding geoname_id for returned subdivisions in CSV files (e.g. `cat GeoLite2-City-Locations-en.csv | grep 11071621` returns nothing).

Is it a bug or expected behavior? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reached out to support and the answer is that this is by design. The CSV files do not include locations if there's no IP directly associated with them.

Read more here: https://github.com/maxmind/MaxMind-DB/issues/61